# SHA1 hmac PHP vs Javascript - Different Results?

Tags: php, javascript, sha1

Hello
I am using class in javascript to hash string:
https://ssl.bsk.com.pl/mobi/js/sha1.js

```
hex_hmac_sha1("927545161", "asdasdasdasdś") ;
```

Result is:
5db0194c834d419fc5d68b72c88af1ac8ee749d6

In PHP i'm hashing:

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1', "asdasdasdasdś", '927545161');
```

but result is:
0b115775a20bed9922b6a9cc934cb5328fe71ade

Where is error?
5db0194c834d419fc5d68b72c88af1ac8ee749d6 != 0b115775a20bed9922b6a9cc934cb5328fe71ade

Comment: I also guess it has something to do with file encoding / unicode issue

Comment: I know. I use UTF-8 in php and in JS page. Problem is with UTF-8 chars :< I changed to iso 8859-1, 8859-2.... but still result <> 5db0194c834d419fc5d68b72c88af1ac8ee749d6

Answer (score 5):

PHP interprets the UTF-8 string as sequence of 8-bit chars. Whereas in Javascript each character can resolve to an Unicode code point.

Your compacted and totally unreadable Javascript implementation uses `.charCodeAt()` to transform the string into a hexstring. I didn't bother to investigate it completely, but it's most likely that `"ś".charCodeAt(0)` simply resolves to `347`, and the remainder of the conversion expected a value in the 8-bit range `0` to `255`.

Comment: You’re right. It works with `hex_hmac_sha1("927545161", "asdasdasdasd\xC5\x9B") == "0b115775a20bed9922b6a9cc934cb5328fe71ade"`.

Comment: I cannot change the JS scruot, since this is on other server. It is needed for me to log on in php to the side - there is this login security Is there some solution in PHP?